# Сихронизация 1c и msklad (modx)

Tags: modx, 1с

В файле offers указывается количество товара
Создаю в msklad "поле msProduct" источник "Количество" Цель "number"
в minishop2 создаю поле number

Но количество так и не получаю, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Если ты этот компонент купил, то можешь в админке написать в поддержку и разработчик поможет решить такие вопросы.